# Need to install npm 2.15.5

Tags: node.js, npm

I upgraded to a higher version of npm
But now I can't use `nvm use 4.4.6`

(Which is what I need for this project and cannot be updated), I get:

```
/Users/adrq/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.6/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:87
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v4.4.6` to unset it.
```

I've tried running `nvm use --delete-prefix v4.4.6`

But get the same error

I've read about removing the prefix entirely from the npmrc file

But have no idea how, another option would be to see if I can roll back to the previous version of npm.
I've tried npm install -g 2.15.5, but get

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: 2.15.5@latest
```

Have tried  npm install -g 2 and get

```
+ 2@3.0.0
added 53 packages in 19.338s
```

however running npm -v returns

```
5.5.1
```

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Why? You don't install "a different version of `npm`", you "install a particular version of Node", which will come with the version of `npm` that is compatible with it. Your console log shows you're using an absolutely _ancient_ Node version, so... stop using that? Just run `nvm install --lts` to install the current Long Term Support version of Node (v14.15.4 at the time of this comment) and then `nvm use --lts` to make sure you're actually using it, and now at least you'll be on the most reliable version of Node _and_ its associated `npm` version.

Comment: I need to use node v4.4.6, I can do nvm use 10 or whatever and I don't get that error message, but in order for my app to run it needs to be v4, but when I do nvm use 4.4.6 I get the above error

Comment: You really don't: Node 4 is a giant gaping security hole. It makes far more sense to update your code to work with Node LTS instead of trying to install a version of `npm` that relies on a features that aren't even in Node 4, even if that's not what you want to do. It really is what you should do, in this case. Heck, there won't even be much that you'd need to update, other than possibly look up the new function signatures for some of the standard library functions.

Comment: You are correct, but, I don't have any control over the project, so that's out of the question at the the moment, thanks for your input

Comment: I don't understand: how do you not control the code when you clearly control the installation of node? Anyway, the solution here is to find out which version of _node_, not npm, is required, and then installing that version (which automatically gets you the right version of npm). The error you're showing is about your version of node, not npm, being too old for the code you're trying to run, so just update your node version one LTS at a time until your code runs (try 6. Then 8. Then 10. etc. And then keep trying until you get to 14 because it's almost certainly going to work just fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meant to post this days ago;

Here's what I learned

When you use nvm it loads the version of node as well as the best version of npm to use.

So, when I was using v4.4.6 and did an npm install -g npm, this must have messed this up

I needed to reinstall npm within the node version folder

```
cd ~/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.6/lib
```

And then

```
npm install npm@2.15.5
```

All works fine now